# View is clipping its content - NSPopUpButton only

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode9, xcode-storyboard

[image]In Xcode 9, an NSPopUpButton is now issuing a warning about 'View is clipping its content'.

[image: PopUp button screenshot]

The only satisfying settings seems to be to stretch it horizontally through the view (right and left fixed constraints).

This issue is from a clean project with just this popup button added to the Storyboard. In other words, can be recreated easily.
The constraints are top-left simple fixed to superview with the added (since Xcode 9) right 'greater or equal' to superview with constant as 'standard'.
Also, the warning is not a 'yellow' warning. It only shows when opening the 'Issue Navigator' (⌘5).
I'm assuming of course, that popup buttons are not required to grab the whole view length now.

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue but I can't. Did you change the width or the menu of the popup button?

Comment: @Willeke No, I practically created a new project, dragged the popup button and added top-leading-trailing constrains. This warning is not a yellow warning. It only shows when opening the warning left tab (issues navigator, Cmd+5). (I will edit my question to indicate there's no yellow warning).

Comment: Live issues was switched off. If I add more popup buttons, only one has the problem. Looks like a bug, Google "View is clipping its content".

Comment: @Willeke Yea, "View is clipping its content" is a known issue. Had some of them and all got cleared but this one. This one seems to 'think' it's legit. I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to increase your control size because its contents (NSMenu items which belong to it) are too big to fit inside the NSPopUpButton control.
Your case when you stretched the control to the end of the window satisfied that condition and your control became big enough to contain its contents.

Comment: Just recreated it under Xcode 10. I'm using constraints, so dragging it irrelevant. Also, I did drag and allow it to 'update frames'. Warning still there, easily reproduced as noted.

Comment: There's a good post regarding this bug (from 2017): https://indiestack.com/2017/01/interface-builder-view-is-clipping-its-content/

Comment: It is not a matter of dragging. You just need to increase your control size because its contents (NSMenu items which belong to it) are too big to fit inside the NSPopUpButton control. Your case when you stretched the control to the end of the window satisfied the condition and your control became big enough to contain its contents.

Comment: That's it! If I give it a bigger width (constraints of >= 76 for example), the warning goes away. The initial width is too small (guessing has to do with intrinsic size). If you could add this to the answer, that'll be great. Basically, it needs a bigger width than its initial intrinsic width, depending on the longest item text. Fixed by adding a '>=' width and extending the minimum to the point it's wide enough (warning goes away).

Comment: So... why doesn't this work automatically, without the >= width constraint?  Why doesn't "Size to Fit Content" make it the size it wants to be, first of all; and why doesn't the control express an intrinsic size that makes it happy?  This solution worked for me, too, but I'd like to understand why, and how to handle this issue in a nib that gets localized.